# very strange error in mysql . match against search is working but for right it is not working

Tags: php, mysql

this is working fine if,I search for right button its not giving any  result.But data exist in database

```
SELECT *
FROM tblcodes
WHERE MATCH(search_term) AGAINST('+left* +button* ' in BOOLEAN MODE) OR
      code LIKE '%left button%'
```

please give any suggestion

Comment: Your query seems to be trying to match left button, are you surprised by your results?

Comment: result is ok for left button but for right button it is not giving any result

Comment: Could you get away with this: `WHERE code LIKE '%left button%' OR code LIKE '%right button%'` ?

Comment: wait let me try

Comment: i think this should be WHERE search_term LIKE '%left button%' OR code LIKE '%right button%'

Comment: dont knw why the guys are downvoted this question

Comment: but i want to fetch it by WHERE MATCH(search_term) AGAINST('+left* +button* ' in BOOLEAN MODE) OR
      code LIKE '%left button%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *right* is contained in the [MyISAM fulltext stopword list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html). This means it won't be added to the fulltext index because it is assumed to be too common in english texts to actually help identifying content. So you cannot find it using `match against` (but you would still find it using `like`).

To change that behaviour, you can modify or disable that list:

> To override the default stopword list for MyISAM tables, set the ft_stopword_file system variable. (See Section 6.1.5, “Server System Variables”.) The variable value should be the path name of the file containing the stopword list, or the empty string to disable stopword filtering. The server looks for the file in the data directory unless an absolute path name is given to specify a different directory. After changing the value of this variable or the contents of the stopword file, restart the server and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes.

You can also switch to InnoDB, it uses a much shorter default stopword list, although this might just divert the problem until you are looking for e.g. *about*.

Comment: ya you are right ca we remove it from myisam engine

Comment: @NishantSaini Was this a question on how to do it or the notice that you are going to change to innodb?

Comment: Need a solution in myisam sir

Comment: @NishantSaini The solution is in the quoted text. Change the `ft_stopword_file` system variable to nothing (or a different file), restart the server and rebuild your index.